# Rebuilding recursion from MSSQL Server in Python using Dataframes or arrays - how?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, recursion

I want to translate the following SQL code into Python and implement it with stored data in dataframes. The data is located in the dataframes df_tblObject and df_tblAssignment instead of the SQL tables tblObject and tblAssignment. However, I haven't been successful in reformulating it yet. Here is my current approach, which leads to an error.

Thanks for any ideas and suggestions.

SQL Code:

```
WITH t(level, path, Object_ID, objectType, calculationType, unit, fiscalYear, month, quantity) AS (
        SELECT 1,
                CAST(Object_ID AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                Object_ID,
                objectType,
                CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(8000)), 
                CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                CAST(1 AS FLOAT)
        FROM tblObject
        WHERE Object_ID = 99999999999999 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT t.level + 1,
                t.path + '.' + CAST(c.Object_ID AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                c.Object_ID,
                c.objectType,
                CAST(z.calculationType AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                CAST(z.unit AS VARCHAR(8000)),
        CAST(z.fiscalYear AS VARCHAR(8000)),
        CAST(z.month AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                t.quantity * CAST(z.quantity AS FLOAT)
        FROM t
        INNER JOIN tblAssignment z
        ON t.Object_ID = z.Mother_ID
        INNER JOIN tblObject c
        ON z.Child_ID = c.Object_ID
        WHERE t.level + 1 <= 100 AND z.calculationType = 'Standard' AND z.fiscalYear = '2024' AND z.month = '1'
)
```

Python Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Annahme: df_tblObject und df_tblAssignment sind Ihre Pandas DataFrames

# Funktion für die rekursive Abfrage
def recursive_query(level, path, Object_ID, objectType, calculationType, unit, fiscalYear, month, quantity):
    # Basisfall
    if level == 1:
        return pd.DataFrame({
            'level': [1],
            'path': [str(Object_ID)],
            'Object_ID': [Object_ID],
            'objectType': [objectType],
            'calculationType': [None],
            'unit': [None],
            'fiscalYear': [None],
            'month': [None],
            'quantity': [1.0]
        })

    # Rekursiver Fall
    else:
        # Filterkriterien anwenden
        filtered_assignments = df_tblAssignment[
            (df_tblAssignment['Mother_ID'] == Object_ID) &
            (df_tblAssignment['calculationType'] == 'Standard') &
            (df_tblAssignment['fiscalYear'] == '2024') &
            (df_tblAssignment['month'] == '1')
        ]

        # Verbindung mit tblObject
        merged_data = pd.merge(filtered_assignments, df_tblObject, left_on='Child_ID', right_on='Object_ID')


        recursive_results = pd.concat([
         recursive_query(level + 1, path + '.' + str(row['Object_ID']), row['Object_ID'], row['objectType'],
                            row['calculationType'], row['unit'], row['fiscalYear'], row['month'], quantity * float(row['quantity']))
            for _, row in merged_data.iterrows()
        ], ignore_index=True)

        return recursive_results


start_object_id = 99999999999999 
initial_data = df_tblObject[df_tblObject['Object_ID'] == start_object_id]

result = recursive_query(1, str(start_object_id), start_object_id, initial_data['objectType'].values[0], None, None, None, None, 1.0)

print (result)
```

Comment: For Pythoners unfamiliar with recursive CTEs, please explain what that SQL code does. Rolling sum of quantity by group? Also, post exact error message raised. Finally, a data sample with posted code would help for [mre]. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1422451)